# nginx matches 127.0.0.1 before *:80

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have the following two server directives setup by including conf.d/*.conf. When I navigate to the server via the public, external IP address it seems to match the server for 127.0.0.1 as an entry is added to the localhost.access_log file. I expected this to only happen when accessing via localhost. From an external IP I expected to match the .host.tld `server_name` directive or the `default_server` parameter.

Do I need to ensure an order to how the conf files are loaded? Why would the listen on 127.0.0.1 be matched in this way? Is it the second location directive that is empty?

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name .host.tld;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/host.error_log info;

    root /var/www/host/htdocs;

    location = / {
            index index.php index.html;
    }

    location / {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing both `listen` directives to `80` and adding the `127.0.0.1` name to the `server_name` of the `localhost` segment fixed it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name .host.tld;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/host.error_log info;

    root /var/www/host/htdocs;

    location = / {
            index index.php index.html;
    }

    ...
}
```